# GAE: 'Response' object has no attribute 'set_cookie'

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies, response, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to test a customized Session for Google AppEngine (1.9.15). It uses `response.set_cookie()`. Printing `dir(response)` doesn't show the function exists. Any ideas how I can get a `response` object that has this function?

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
response = webapp.Response()
pprint(dir(response))

google.appengine.ext.webapp._webapp25.Response object at 0x100e6d110>
['_Response__HTTP_STATUS_MESSAGES',
 '_Response__status',
 '_Response__wsgi_headers',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'clear',
 'has_error',
 'headers',
 'http_status_message',
 'out',
 'set_status',
 'status',
 'status_message',
 'wsgi_write']
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html) the response is built by the request handler (in response to a request), so try to print it **inside** one of the  handlers of your app:

> The request handler instance builds the response using its response
>   property. This is initialized to an empty WebOb Response object by the
>   application.
>
> The response object’s acts as a file-like object that can be used for
>   writing the body of the response:
>
> ```
> class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
>     def get(self):
>         self.response.write("<html><body><p>Hi there!</p></body></html>")
> ```

Comment: I wanted to test just the session without any handlers around it - to keep it simple. :-) Do you know where exactly the cookies functionality is added? I should be able to do it manually.

Comment: To test the session you can just store/retrieve some arbitrary value in it. What you were trying was setting the cookies in a response, which you can't do without a handler.